# Seemingly automatic pointer freeing

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function whichtakes a file, reads it line by line, puts every line in a `*char[]`, puts this twodimensional array in a struct, and returns this struct:
wordlist.h:

```
#ifndef H_WORDLIST
#define H_WORDLIST
typedef struct {
    char **chWordsList;
    int listlen;
}Wordlist;
Wordlist getWordlistFromFile(char *chFilename);
char *getRandomWord();
#endif
```

The function (plus headers):

```
#include "wordlist.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDSIZE 100

Wordlist getWordlistFromFile(char *chFilename){
    FILE *file = fopen(chFilename,"r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file %s. Check if the file exists and can be read by this user.\n",chFilename);
        exit(1);
    }
    char chWord[WORDSIZE];
    int intFileSize = 0;
    //First: coundt the amount of lines in the file
    while((fgets(chWord,WORDSIZE,file) != NULL)){
        ++intFileSize;
    }
    rewind(file);
    char *chWordList[intFileSize];
    for (int count = 0; (fgets(chWord,WORDSIZE,file) != NULL); ++count){
        chWordList[count] = malloc( strlen(chWord +1));
        strcpy(chWordList[count],chWord);
        chWordList[count][strlen(chWord) -1] = 0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    Wordlist wordlist;
    wordlist.chWordsList = chWordList;
    wordlist.listlen = intFileSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.listlen; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", wordlist.chWordsList[i]);
    }
    return wordlist;
}
```

So far this works great. The last for loop prints exactly every line of the given file, all fully expected behaviour, works perfect. Now, I actually want to use the function. So: in my main.c:

```
Wordlist list = getWordlistFromFile(strFilePath);
for (int i = 0; i < list.listlen; ++i){
    printf("%s\n", list.chWordsList[i]);
}
```

This gives me the weirdest output:

```
abacus
wordlist
(null)
(null)
��Ⳏ
E����H�E
gasses
```

While the output should be:

```
abacus
amused
amours
arabic
cocain
cursor
gasses
```

It seems to me almost like some pointers get `free`d or something, while others stay intact. What is going on? Why is `wordlist` perfect before the return and broken after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *chWordList[intFileSize]
```

This array of strings is allocated on stack since it's declared as a local of `getWordlistFromFile`. Upon exiting the function the stack pointer is decreased and the array is no longer valid.

You should use the same approach used for the single string: allocate in on heap.

```
char **chWordList = malloc(intFileSize*sizeof(char*))
```

In this way the array will persist the scope of the function and you will be able to use it after the call to the function.

Comment: Why sizeof(char*)? I see that sizeof(char) does not work, and I am wondering why :)?

Comment: Because you are allocating `intFileSize` pointers to `char`. Each pointer is almost certainly larger than `char`.

Comment: And how much space are you actually allocating with sizeof(char*)? Or is that somehow dynamic?

Comment: It's platform dependent. It is mostly 32 or 64 bit according to the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning pointers to objects whose lifetime has expired. In particular, `chWordsList` inside the return value points to an object whose lifetime ends when the function returns. When you dereference that pointer you get undefined behavior (UB); therefore *any* result would not be surprising.

What you need to do is `malloc` memory for the `chWordList` instead of declaring it as a local array:

```
char **chWordList = malloc(intFileSize * sizeof(char*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char *chWordList[intFileSize];
```

to

```
char **chWordList = malloc(sizeof(char *) * intFileSize);
```

i.e allocated `chwordList` and set that in the `WordList`.

Your code is returning array variable `chWordList` allocated on stack, so it will not be valid once the function `getWordlistFromFile()` completes and returns to `main()`.